# ADO - Parse String URL and use parameters

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing, ado

I am reading table rows from **SQL**  into **VB.net webform** where the values contain **URLs** as **string**

Example:

> /TEST/Receiver.ashx?input=3&HLR=&sessionID=138&cellid=&datetime=2013120916545057&isnewrequest=0

I'm reading all values with **SqlDataReader**

I want to take this String and parse it into  : **input** , **sessionID** , **cellid** , **datetime** , **isnewrequest**

then display those **parameters** and their **values**.

Any idea how to do this?

I tried everything.

Comment: That's not a valid URL.  Is that the complete string?

Comment: @StevenDoggart Yes. I just want the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Split the String, and iterate over it,
First you have to split it at the '?' for the query parameters, then split it at the '&',

iterate over all pairs you have and split them at the '=' and add key, value to a List :)

```
Dim myString As String = "/TEST/Receiver.ashx?input=3&HLR=&sessionID=138&cellid=&datetime=2013120916545057&isnewrequest=0"
Dim pairs As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()
Dim keyValuePairs() As String = myString.Split("?"c)(1).Split("&"c)
For Each pair As String In keyValuePairs
    Dim kp() As String = pair.Split("="c)
    pairs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(kp(0), kp(1)))
Next pair
```

Comment: Did you forget that you're on the VB.NET (dark)side?

Comment: This is a good example of how to parse it yourself without using the built-in URI parsing.  +1 for a good example and for taking the time to convert it to VB :)

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid URL, you can parse it using the built-in functionality of the `HttpUtility` class, like this:

```
Dim myUri As New Uri(urlString)
Dim input As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("input")
```

However, the example you posted is not a valid URL, so it will throw an exception.  To fix it, you'd need to add a valid prefix to the string, like this:

```
Dim partialUrlFromDb As String = "/TEST/Receiver.ashx?input=3&HLR=&sessionID=138&cellid=&datetime=2013120916545057&isnewrequest=0"
Dim baseUri As New Uri("http://myfakesite")
Dim myUri As New Uri(baseUri, partialUrlFromDb)
Dim input As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("input")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way but q1,q2,q3,q4 gives you the  input , sessionID , cellid , datetime , isnewrequest

```
 s = "/TEST/Receiver.ashx?input=3&HLR=&sessionID=138&cellid=&datetime=2013120916545057&isnewrequest=0 " ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    s1 = InStr(s, "=")

    s2 = InStr(s, "=&")

    q1 = Mid(s, s1 + 1, (s2 - s1) - 1) 'Input

    f1 = Mid(s, s2 + 1) ''''''''''''''''''''''''

    s1 = InStr(f1, "=")

    s2 = InStr(f1, "=&")

    q2 = Mid(f1, s1 + 1, (s2 - s1) - 1) 'Session Id

    f2 = Mid(f1, s2 + 2) '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    s1 = InStr(f2, "=")

    s2 = InStr(f2, "&")

    q3 = Mid(f2, s1 + 1, (s2 - s1) - 1) 'Dattime

    f3 = Mid(f2, s2 + 1)

    s1 = InStr(f3, "=") '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    q4 = Mid(s, s1 + 1) 'isnewrequest
```